# What is the difference between defaultSystemOutputDevice and defautOutputdevice in MacOS?

Tags: macos

What is the difference between defaultSystemOutputDevice and defautOutputdevice?

kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultSystemOutputDevice vs kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation in the header ($SDKROOT/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/Headers/AudioHardware.h):

```
@constant       kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice
                    The AudioObjectID of the default output AudioDevice.
@constant       kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultSystemOutputDevice
                    The AudioObjectID of the output AudioDevice to use for system related sound
                    from the alert sound to digital call progress.
```

I think this has to do with a setting in the Sound pane of System Preferences. On the Sound Effects tab, there's a pop-up for "Play sound effects through:". You can configure it to follow the selected output device on the Output tab or specify a particular device. I believe this setting corresponds to `kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultSystemOutputDevice` because of the mention of the alert sound in its description. `kAudioHardwarePropertyDefaultOutputDevice` would correspond to the setting on the Output tab.